# match the exact word and replace the word using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working in xslt based conversion. I need to replace the word in one element to the other element which exactly matches. But currently it was matching partially also.

My input is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<doc>
    <section>
        <key>SERVICE</key>
        <title>ABOUT SERVICES (OUR SERVICE) OF THE CONCERN(SERVICE)</title>
    </section>
    <section>
        <key>SERVICES</key>
        <title>ABOUT NEW SERVICES, TO DO CONCERN(SERVICE)</title>
    </section>
    <section>
        <key>LOOK</key>
        <title>IT LOOKING SO, BUT "LOOK" GOOD</title>
    </section>
</doc>
```

I need to find the key element word in the title element and replace with <b>keyword</b>. The matches should be exact.

But currently it replacing for all partial matches also as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <section>
        <key>SERVICE</key>
        ABOUT &lt;b&gt;SERVICE&lt;/b&gt;S (OUR &lt;b&gt;SERVICE&lt;/b&gt;) OF THE CONCERN(&lt;b&gt;SERVICE&lt;/b&gt;)
    </section>
    <section>
        <key>SERVICES</key>
        ABOUT NEW &lt;b&gt;SERVICES&lt;/b&gt;, TO DO CONCERN(SERVICE)
    </section>
    <section>
        <key>LOOK</key>
        IT &lt;b&gt;LOOK&lt;/b&gt;ING SO, BUT "&lt;b&gt;LOOK&lt;/b&gt;" GOOD
    </section>
</doc>
```

My xslt is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:variable name="k-word-text">
      <xsl:text>&lt;b&gt;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::key"/>
      <xsl:text>&lt;/b&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="matches(., preceding-sibling::key)">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., preceding-sibling::key, $k-word-text)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below my expecting output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <section>
        <key>SERVICE</key>
        ABOUT SERVICES (OUR &lt;b&gt;SERVICE&lt;/b&gt;) OF THE CONCERN(&lt;b&gt;SERVICE&lt;/b&gt;)
    </section>
    <section>
        <key>SERVICES</key>
        ABOUT NEW &lt;b&gt;SERVICES&lt;/b&gt;, TO DO CONCERN(SERVICE)
    </section>
    <section>
        <key>LOOK</key>
        IT LOOKING SO, BUT "&lt;b&gt;LOOK&lt;/b&gt;" GOOD
    </section>
</doc>
```

Comment: Do note that markup encoding shouldn't be necessary using `xsl:analize-string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create a variable to hold the text you wish to match, but include regular expressions to ensure the key is not preceded or followed by a letter

```
<xsl:variable name="k-match-text">
  <xsl:text>(^|[^A-Za-z])</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::key"/>
  <xsl:text>($|[^A-Za-z])</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```

Note, you don't actually need the `xsl:choose` with `contains` here, as if the text does not contain the key, the `replace` statement will leave the text the same regardless.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:variable name="k-word-text">
      <xsl:text>$1&lt;b&gt;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::key"/>
      <xsl:text>&lt;/b&gt;$2</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="k-match-text">
      <xsl:text>(^|[^A-Za-z])</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::key"/>
      <xsl:text>($|[^A-Za-z])</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $k-match-text, $k-word-text)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The code you mentioned was working, but in the last title <title>IT LOOKING SO, BUT "LOOK" GOOD</title> the quotes are missing in the output i.e.  IT LOOKING SO, BUT &lt;b&gt;LOOK&lt;/b&gt; GOOD

Comment: Oops! I've made a change so that `$k-word-text` contains the placeholders to ensure the surrounding characters are replaced too.